# ChangeDisplaySettings succeeds yet does nothing. How do I get it to work?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am trying to use ChangeDisplaySettings to change the desktop resolution of the default display device. However, when I execute my function (`set_resolution`), ChangeDisplaySettings always succeeds despite making no apparent change to my desktop resolution (the return code is always DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL).

I have tried every value for dwFlags, yet for each value I get the same result. I have tried multiple resolutions that my display should support, yet I get the same result. My display is 16:9, native 1920x1080. I've tried, for example, 1280x720.

I have tried executing `set_resolution` at the same time as creating the window and also I have tried executing the function on every `WM_ACTIVATE` event.

```
LONG set_resolution(uint32_t width, uint32_t height)
{
    DEVMODE dm;

    dm.dmPelsWidth = width;
    dm.dmPelsHeight = height;
    dm.dmBitsPerPel = 32;
    dm.dmDisplayFrequency = 60;
    dm.dmFields =
        DM_PELSWIDTH |
        DM_PELSHEIGHT |
        DM_BITSPERPEL |
        DM_DISPLAYFREQUENCY;

    DWORD flags =
        0;
        //CDS_FULLSCREEN;
        //CDS_GLOBAL;
        //CDS_NORESET;
        //CDS_RESET;
        //CDS_SET_PRIMARY;
        //CDS_TEST;
        //CDS_UPDATEREGISTRY;

    LONG code = ChangeDisplaySettings(&dm, flags);

    if (code == DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
    {
        printf("Display change successful [%dx%d]: %d", width, height, flags);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Display change failed [%dx%d]: %d", width, height, code);
    }

    return code;
}
```

Comment: You're not setting the `dm.dmSize`. When in doubt, read the  [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183411(v=vs.85).aspx) : The dmSize member of DEVMODE must be initialized to the size, in bytes, of the DEVMODE structure. The dmDriverExtra member of DEVMODE must be initialized to indicate the number of bytes of private driver data following the DEVMODE structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zero the memory first, then set `dmSize`. Call [`EnumDisplaySettings`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162611(v=vs.85).aspx) to initialize the other members.

It would be a good idea to have a routine to undo changes automatically in case the settings were incompatible and resulted in black screen...

```
DEVMODE dm;
memset(&dm, 0, sizeof(dm));
dm.dmSize = sizeof(dm);

if (0 != EnumDisplaySettings(NULL, ENUM_CURRENT_SETTINGS, &dm))
{
    int savew = dm.dmPelsWidth;
    int saveh = dm.dmPelsHeight;
    dm.dmPelsWidth = width;
    dm.dmPelsHeight = height;

    LONG result = ChangeDisplaySettings(&dm, 0);
    if (result == DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL)
    {
        printf("okay\n");

        //Add a dialog to ask the user to confirm.
        //The dialog should close automatically if user is unable to confirm
        //if (confirm()) return;
        Sleep(5000);

        dm.dmPelsWidth = savew;
        dm.dmPelsHeight = saveh;
        ChangeDisplaySettings(&dm, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("error\n");
    }
}
```

*Edit, fixed typo. I meant to say call  `EnumDisplaySettings` to initialize `DEVMODE`'s members*

Comment: You have put the code to restore settings in the `DISP_CHANGE_SUCCESSFUL` branch. Is this intended? I also don't understand, why it would be wise to restore settings in case of an error. If the API call fails, there won't be any changes to undo.

Comment: I think it's more of a "does this look good to you" sort of prompt.  To let the user change their mind if they don't like it or it doesn't work.

Comment: @IInspectable The standard Windows display settings uses a routine which will undo the changes if user doesn't say "Yes, I want to keep the new settings".  I wrote something simple which will automatically undo the changes. Otherwise somebody executes this code and they may end up with a black screen, and they have no way to undo the changes.